# Specifying Table/grid dimensions in version 7

Tags: output-formatting, version-7

The result of my calculations is quite large list (nested list to be precise). I would like to improve its visualization, to make it more legible, by setting the number of columns to let's say 5. Documentation Center suggests an option `AllowedDimensions`, but it is new in ver 9. How can I make it happen in version 7? Thanks for any hints.

**Edit:**
The list has two sublists of equal length, simple example would be:

```
list={{45.1,73.5,12.9,56.4,114.6,87.1,90.5,263.8,99.3,104.6},
     {0.34,0.12,0.56,0.95,0.25,0.57,1.03,0.73,0.92,1.02}};
```

**Edit 1:**
After setting the number of columns to 5 it should look more or less like this:

```
{{45.1,73.5,12.9,56.4,114.6,
  87.1,90.5,263.8,99.3,104.6},
 {0.34,0.12,0.56,0.95,0.25,
  0.57,1.03,0.73,0.92,1.02}};
```

Comment: We need more details from you but in the absence of any clarifying information If you have some data, nested or otherwise, and you want to present it as 5 columns then have a look at `Flatten` and `Partition`. The nesting may mean it is not as straight forward as that but until you post an example that is all I can suggest.

Comment: For some reasons I would like the list to stay nested, so I'd like to avoid `Flatten`.

Comment: Can you post an example of the nested data and an example of how that nested data should look when transformed into 5 columns.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I'm the only one still using ver 7... However, if by any chance someone is as stubborn as me and also uses ver 7, I found a way to solve this problem. At least it works for me.

It is `PageWidth` option that helps here. I followed the Basic Examples in Documentation Center and came up with the following code:

```
file1 = $TemporaryPrefix <> "test1";
list = {{45.1, 73.5, 12.9, 56.4, 114.6, 87.1, 90.5, 263.8, 99.3,104.6}, 
        {0.34, 0.12, 0.56, 0.95, 0.25, 0.57, 1.03, 0.73, 0.92,1.02}};
stream = OpenWrite[file1, PageWidth -> 35];
Write[stream, list];
Close[stream];
FilePrint[file1]
```

`PageWidth->n` specifies that each line of the `stream` should be wide for n characters, after some calculations I was able to determine this value to be around 35 in my case and the result was pretty much what I wanted:

> {{45.1, 73.5, 12.9, 56.4, 114.6,
>
> 87.1, 90.5, 263.8, 99.3, 104.6},
>
> {0.34, 0.12, 0.56, 0.95, 0.25,
>
> 0.57, 1.03, 0.73, 0.92, 1.02}}

I believe that `list` can be created not only explicitly like here, but any other way for example using `Table`.